# How to capture user's MAC address with NodeMCU and enduser_setup?

Tags: c, file, http, nodemcu

I am trying to modify [`enduser_setup`](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/enduser-setup/) module to act as Captive portal. 
I found [this](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/modules/enduser_setup.c) source code. It looks like I am supposed to modify the function [`enduser_setup_http_serve_html`](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/modules/enduser_setup.c#L760) function to add logging of user's MAC address. I.e. I would like to write a text file like below:

```
04/03/2018 23:03 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee
04/03/2018 23:04 bb:aa:cc:dd:ee
```

(each time user opens my page, new line with his/her MAC address should be added to the file)

I never worked with C before, so I have the following questions:

1. have I chosen the function correctly? or should it be [`enduser_setup_http_recvcb`](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/modules/enduser_setup.c#L1121) instead?
2. how could I get user's MAC address? does `http_client` variable contain it?
3. how to write log file? I tried to see how debug works there -

   ```
   static void enduser_setup_debug(int line, const char *str)
    {
      lua_State *L = lua_getstate();
      if(state != NULL && state->lua_dbg_cb_ref != LUA_NOREF)
      {
        lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, state->lua_dbg_cb_ref);
        lua_pushfstring(L, "%d: \t%s", line, str);
        lua_call(L, 1, 0);
      }
    }
   ```

But I don't understand which file is being modified there. Looks like another option is to write file with direct [`vfs.h`](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/c8ac5cfb912ff206b03dd7c60ffbb2dafb83fe5e/app/platform/vfs.h) usage like `file_fd = vfs_open(output, "w+")`, but I can not find clear example from existing NodeMCU modules.

Answer (score 0):

Working in C is a learning leap.  Doing embedded C development is a learning leap for a C programmer.  Developing or modifying NodeMCU firmware libraries is a learning leap for a embedded C developer.

What I am trying to suggest is that there are just too many steps for you to accomplish here in one go and issues that you haven't begun to grasp.

Where do you want this text file to be created?  Because the VFS will only write to files on the file system internal to the ESP module.  And the MAC address is directly accessible in Lua running one the ESP module anyway.

I suggest that what you are trying to do is to log the mac address of any ESP being configured using the setup library off chip, and that means talking over IP -- which you can't do before you have configured the IP stack.

However, the embedded Lua app that you will run on the configured ESP can always use the `http` module, say, to log the IP (and other) configuration to some web service.